# Undefined method `after_create_commit' for Message:Class Did you mean? after_create - Rails action cable tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried to follow the [ActionCable tutorial - Site point](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-chat-app-with-rails-5-actioncable-and-devise/) and I convert this tutorial to using MongoDB . But I have the problems with devise

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

undefined method `after_create_commit' for Message:Class Did you mean? after_create
```

I don't have any ideas about this problems . Please help me , thank you so much.

message.rb

```
class Message
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :body, type: String

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :chat_room

validates :body, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2, maximum: 1000}

after_create_commit { MessageBroadcastJob.perform_later(self) }

def timestamp
    created_at.strftime('%H:%M:%S %d %B %Y')
end
```

end

Comment: `after_create_commit` is a method [in `ActiveRecord`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/ActiveRecord%2FTransactions%2FClassMethods%3Aafter_create_commit). Your `Message` class doesn't inherit from `ActiveRecord` right now, since you are using Mongo.

Comment: oh . now I know , thank you so much .

Comment: Is there any function similar to after_create_commit  use for mongod ?

Comment: I couldn't tell you -- I avoid MongoDB with my Rails apps 

Answer (score 0):

Got turbo-broadcasting from models work with mongoid. The steps were:

1. use 'after_create' instead of 'after_create_commit' etc., since mongoid has different callbacks (you can check the full list [here](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html))
2. 'include Turbo::Broadcastable' in your model

Hope this helps to someone.